# How is Paginate Pipe Successfully Accessing the Length of Array in Angular 2 App?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pagination

I have one of those interesting situations where I have some code that is working in my Angular 2 app - in that it's generating the correct value - but I am not sure exactly how it's accomplishing that.

Specifically, I am using ng2-pagination to handle pagination in my app. The way I'm using it, one inputs the number of results per page desired, and by calculating that against the length of the array of results, the correct number of pages is generated for the pagination.

In my case, the correct # of pages is being generated - which tells me that the ng2-pagination is successfully doing that math. But I'm not entirely sure where it's currently getting the length of the array.

Here's the relevant code I have in my component. Basically it's calling a service and running two functions that fire in the OnInit cycle. The first gets all the records. And the second gets the total count of those records:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.customerService.getAll()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.records = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);

    this.customerService.getCustomerCount()
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => this.customerCount = resRecordsData,
        responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
}
```

Then, in my view, I am iterating over those items, and passing them through the paginate pipe, like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records | paginate: { id: 'customers', itemsPerPage: 15, currentPage: page }">
```

I am also setting some of the parameters for the paginate-pipe in the view with this code:

```
<div *ngIf="!!records && records.length" class="pagination">
                    <pagination-controls class="paginator" (pageChange)="page = $event" id="customers"
                            maxSize="15"
                            directionLinks="true"
                            autoHide="true">
                    </pagination-controls>
            </div>
```

Now currently I have just under 900 records in this collection. And with the above code, the correct number of pages are being generated in the view. In other words, because the collection contains just under 900 items, and I have set the per page display to 15, it's generating exactly 60 pages - which is correct!

The question is, how is the pipe getting the info re: the 900 items, since I don't seem to be passing that in anywhere?

Comment: It's acessing the collection.length inside the pipe, just it.

Comment: Because of "let records of records" you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's asking the records array for its length and using that.

[Check the source code for the pagination pipe.](https://github.com/michaelbromley/ng2-pagination/blob/master/src/paginate.pipe.ts)

Comment: So you're saying that it's in the "let record of records" part of the *ngFor that the paginate pipe is accessing the length of the array? So it doesn't need to be passed in as an argument then? Is that correct?

Comment: it IS being passed - as the argument to the paginate pipe.

Comment: It's being passed in "let record of records", correct?

Comment: Yeah,  when you say, records | paginate,    then records will be passed as the parameter to the paginate pipe's transform method.   (ignore the let record of ... part - that's just syntactic sugar - records is the actual parameter)